# Adding stacktrace in zephyr test execution using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testng, jira-zephyr

we currently have our framework that automatically updates the test execution status in zephyr, I want to improve upon that by adding the stack trace to failed executions as a comment, I am struggling to find any documentation on this, I was wondering if anyone knows if this is possible and if anyone has any documentation that will help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with the following method

```
public void updateFailedTest(Scenario scenario) {
            String body = "{\"comment\":\"" + logError(scenario) + "\"}";
            request = given()
                    .auth()
                    .preemptive()
                    .basic(System.getenv("USER_NAME"), System.getenv("ZAPI_PASSWORD"))
                    .header("Accept", "application/json")
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .body(body);
            response = request.when().put(readPropertiesFile("ZEPHYR_API_URL") + "/execution/" + executionId + "/execute");
            response.then().log().ifError().statusCode(200);
            response.then().log().all();
    }
```